# Browser Event Close In ADF

Tags: javascript, java, jsf, oracle-adf

i have JSF Page And I want Detect Browser Event Close When User try close

Tab Or all Browser stop him and if he want leave this page or stay 
    and  i need call java method in backend  through
java script 
    i try do this but  server listener on Page dosen`t see action from js 
    so i need help to make this success

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
    console.log(" Test Event Console .")
    var docComponent = AdfPage.PAGE.findComponentByAbsoluteId('d1');

    console.log(" value component = " + docComponent);

    var dialogText = ' browser Is Closed  !.. ';
    console.log(dialogText);

   var x = AdfCustomEvent.queue(docComponent, "test",{"test":"so"},false);
   console.log("test " + x);
    var y = 0;


    event.returnValue = dialogText;

    return x;
};


<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<f:view xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" xmlns:af="http://xmlns.oracle.com/adf/faces/rich">
     <af:document title="testBrowserChrome.jsf" id="d1" clientComponent="true"  onunload="onbeforeunload">
      <af:form id="f1">
          <af:resource type="javascript" source="resources/js/BrowserEventClose.js"/>
          <af:serverListener type="test" method="#{viewScope.ServerTest.testServerListener}"/>
    </af:form>
    </af:document>

</f:view>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you create a button that has that action and mimic the button trigger using the following code given that **theButton** is the ID of that button.

```
var adfButton = AdfPage.PAGE.findComponentByAbsoluteId("theButton");
AdfActionEvent.queue(adfButton , true /*Immediate*/);
```